# foreach loop as category with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Here is my database :

```
-id    product    prodcut-company  category 
-1    latitude         dell         laptop
-2       .             acer         desktop
-3       .             azus         mouse
-4       .             sony         keyboard
```

+If I have many product separated by category, then I want loop it by category how can I coding and show it in one page then list it as a block like laptop , desktop,...

please help !
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a method in the **model** like this-

```
public function getData(){
    $this->db->from("product_table");
    $this->db->order_by("category");
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        return $q->result();
    }
    return [];
}
```

Fetch data from model using this method in the **controller** and pass this value to the view.

```
$data[
   'products' => $this->your_model->getData()
];
$this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

Loop these values and print in the **view**.

```
...

<?php    
if(!empty($products)){

    $count = count($products);
    $i = 0;

    while($i < $count){

        $category = $products[$i]->category;

        echo '<h3>Category: '.$category.'</h3>';

        echo '<table>
            <tr><th>Product</th><th>Company</th><th>Category</th></tr>
        ';
        for(; $i < $count && $category == $products[$i]->category ; $i++ ){
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$products[$i]->product.'</td>
                <td>'.$products[$i]->company.'</td>
                <td>'.$products[$i]->category.'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
        echo '</table>';

    }

}
?>

...
```

Comment: OK , If I do like this it will loop as one block, it not separated as a block then I also want to add title as a label of block like laptop, desktop, keyboard,....

Comment: OK I'm updating the ans.